# How to pass an AngularJs ng-click function on a button?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to do the following:

```
<form name="newAppointment" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="newAppointment.php">
...
<button ng-click="setMstep(1)">1</button>
<button ng-click="setMstep(5)">5</button>
<button ng-click="setMstep(10)">10</button>
<button ng-click="setMstep(15)">15</button>
...
</form>
```

This needs to be four buttons that can set the interval of selecting minutes.
But when I click on one of the buttons, it will send me to the target location (newAppointment.php) of the `<form>`

When I use the `<a>` tag instead of `<button>`, this will work fine.

Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `type="button"` attribute:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="setMstep(1)">1</button>
```